# How to use a 3rd party node Package in angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I wanted to fetch a list countries in my service for which I found a package for [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-state-city).

But I am unable to import, I ran the following command:

```
npm i country-state-city
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import and use the library like that:

```js
import * as countryStateCity from 'country-state-city';
```